# xref-find-references and its seemingly random "Select project: " behavior

Tags: xref

My daily workflow involves opening a number of diverse projects and navigating through them using Emacs. For *some* projects, `xref-find-references` requires me to select a project (with a "Select project:") prompt - as if it is unable to deduce the project root itself.

What is the reason for this seemingly random `xref-find-references` behavior and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you specify an example a "some project"? Can you provide a recipe, starting with `emacs -Q`, to reproduce what you're seeing? That might help others help you.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when none of the directories up the path are git repositories (or other repositories of another source control system that your `project` package can recognize). Solution: navigate to what you consider the root of the project and run `git init`.

In more detail `xref-find-references` [calls](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/xref.el#L1468) `xref-backend-references`, which invokes `(project-current t)` [here](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/xref.el#L283). The `project` package attempts to decide what is the project root and if it cannot find files that indicate a git (or other source control repository), it interactively [displays](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/progmodes/project.el#L1474) the "Select project: " prompt.